# Sample React Native project with typescript has lots of type errors

Tags: typescript, react-native

I followed the docs to generate a sample project.

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Then I started the project and run

```
tsc
```

I got 183 errors, seems that all of them are from the node_modules

```
3237             use: React.SVGProps<SVGUseElement>;
                 ~~~

  node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3234:13
    3234             use: React.SVGProps<SVGUseElement>;
                     ~~~
    'use' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-test-renderer/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3238:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'view' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>'.

3238             view: React.SVGProps<SVGViewElement>;
                 ~~~~

  node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3235:13
    3235             view: React.SVGProps<SVGViewElement>;
                     ~~~~
    'view' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3047:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

3047         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/react-test-renderer/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3048:14
    3048         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.


Found 183 errors.
```

The current solution that I have is not perfect. I added this line

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

to the tsconfig file, but the complier with ignore all .d.ts file outside the node_modules.

#### Could anyone come up with a better solution?

#### Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to upgrade @types/node?

Comment: try to run with `--skipLibCheck`, which should prevent form checking `node_modules`-directory.

Comment: @Juanjo It is already up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have two conflicting type definitions from different copies of the same module. `@types/react` in particular.

As you can see in your error log it refers to `@types/react` and `@types/react-test-renderer/.../@types/react`. This happens because `@types/react-test-renderer` has incompatible version of `@types/react` dependency and npm/yarn has to install both of them into your `node_modules`. This could be solved (most of the times) with [yarn's resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions) feature.

Though `--skipLibCheck` is pretty common practice to mitigate this kind of issues. Beside the fact that enabling it greatly improves compile times on large projects.